# Edge identification implies vertex identification (but not vice versa)?

Tags: algebraic-topology

This may be an obvious question, but just to ask it to be sure.

Q1) When we identify edges, is it automatically assumed that we identify the vertices as well?

E.g: We have a 2-simplex with vertices $v_0, v_1, v_2$, and we identify all three edges to a single edge. Then all the vertices are identified to a single vertex as well right?

Q2) The converse: Identifying vertices does not imply identifying the edges. Is that correct?

E.g. Using the same example of the 2-simplex. If we identify all the vertices, the edges may not be identified?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regard to your first question, the answer is no, we do not necessarily identify all vertices unless we expressly say so.  Take for example the identification of the square into the cylinder.  In this gluing, we identify one pair of opposing edges of the square, but we only identify the endpoints of these edges in *pairs* ($A$ with $A'$ and $B$ with $B'$).

[image]

(If, as you suggested, we identified all the vertices too we'd arrive at a space homotopic to a punctured torus.)

For your second question, yes that is correct.  A good example here is gluing the square into the torus:

[image]

In this gluing, all four corners of the square get identified, but the edges, critically, do not.  To see this, note that the pair of identified green edges become the green loop on the torus, whereas the two red edges become the red loop!